# Problem reading profile settings and config in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config-server

I have created a project with Spring Boot 3.My docker file is as follows

```
FROM amazoncorretto:17.0.3-alpine
ENV APP_HOME=/usr/app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY ./build/libs/*.jar ./app.jar
RUN chmod +x ./app.jar
RUN touch /app.jar
CMD ["java","-jar","-Dspring.profiles.active=prod","app.jar"]
```

I build Docker with this command:

```
cd /opt/ci-gateway-service
docker build -t gateway-service:latest .
docker run -d \
--name gateway-service \
-p 8060:8060 \
--restart always \
-v db-data:/opt/data \
-e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod" \
-e BUILDKIT_STEP_LOG_MAX_SIZE=1073741824 \
-e spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://192.168.2.97:8088 \
--network core-network \
gateway-service
```

Here is my bootstrap.yml file

```
spring:
    application:
        name: agent-service
    config:
        import: "optional:configserver:http://localhost:8088"
    cloud:
        config:
           enabled: true
---
spring:
    config:
        import: "optional:configserver:http://192.168.2.97:8088"
        activate:
            on-profile: prod
    cloud:
        config:
            enabled: truer
```

The problem is that despite the fact that the program is explicitly told to run with the production profile, it still runs with the dev profile and reads the dev codes from the config server.Does anyone know where the problem is?

I have even written in the command line during Docker build to build Docker with prod profile. But the test result showed no change

Comment: maybe you should tried to read the config from environmnet .

Comment: @Dolphin I have to read the settings from the config server

Comment: spring.config.import can not be overridden. The first one in your file will always be evaluated